# Truth table vs multiplication in probability

Tags: probability

Can I use a truth table with a penalty shoot question in probability? Eg the chance of scoring only the 3rd penalty could be NNY where N is not scoring and Y is scoring out of a possible 8 outcomes on 3 shots. This would seem to be 1 out of 8.
I get different answers if I do it this way and the multiplication of outcomes method.
I fell I'm missing something very obvious here!

Comment: What do you get if you do the mutliplication of outcome method?

Comment: If the probability of success were $1/2$ for each shot, then both methods would give you the same answer.  However, if the probability is not $1/2$, simply listing sequences of penalty shots will not tell you the probability of scoring for the first time on the third shot.

Comment: I should clarify that the shooter has a 75% chance of scoring so both methods are not the same (thanks N.F. Taussig)

Comment: the first part of the question asks the chance of scoring all three which is 3/4 x 3/4 x 3/4 = 27/60 or near 42%.

Comment: If I use the truth table there is only one situation out of 8 where he scores which implies 1/8. But using the same logic on the first part is also 1/8 ie YYY. This seems intuitively wrong but I don't know why.